# Issues with mailing username and password directly to user?

Tags: php, security, passwords

I am building a basic application where user can create an account. User can keep the username as simple as `alex`. There can be multiple users with username `alex`. For each of them I will generate a unique key to be used as password. Key can be `a3exyG`, `alevuQ` or something like that. This key will be mailed to the user along with username. Later these can be used for login. My question is does this pose any security issue. I mean if some one else can already access the email id of user he/she will be able to reset password anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I wouldn't do that. Usernames should be unique (to avoid any issues down the line) and passwords should always be hashed in the database and chosen by the user.

When you authenticate the password entered should be hashed and compared to the value in the database...a one way street.

Passwords never mailed to users.

If you need to reset a forgotten password I'd create a token that expires and email a link with that token to the user that takes them to a page to enter a new password.

edit:
I'd say the risk of someone being able to access someone's email is far less than having plain text stored passwords, passwords being mailed around and duplicate usernames on your system.

Answer (score 1):

You should not send/store sensible data in plain text. What is usually done is to send the user a link to your webpage where the user can set the password.

What would I do:

- Let the user choose it's own password when is signing up
- Store the password hashed
- If you are using an ID instead of the EMAIL to do the sign up you should make them be unique, as it's not very secure that someone has the same ID as me and I misstype a password and accidentally login into other user account.

Another option is to force the user to change his password in the website after logging in with a password received through email.

More information:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/17979/is-sending-password-to-user-email-secure

Comment: If someone already has access to the email Id they can set or reset the password any way. So, what is the point of additional complexity.

Comment: @SujataHulsurkar It's not additional complexity, it's just plain security. I can choose a common username like alex and start trying common passwords, maybe one of the alex's has a dictionary password and can login easily into people's account

Comment: I decide the passwords which are random strings based on username. Sorry, If i sound dumb.  I am just trying to understand the main problem with this method.

Comment: @SujataHulsurkar I edited my answer so you can have some more sources of information and understand by yourself why it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Can users change their password? If they can you will have a problem if there are two entries matching the same user and password...

Comment: No, If they request password reset I will mail them a similarly randomly generated key that does not clash with others.

Comment: @SujataHulsurkar you can just send them to their email a link to your webpage where they can put the new password for their account.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to what @Gori said, I think it's a matter of responsibility on the developer's part.

It is not secure (thus irresponsible) to email any kind of sensitive data (like your password), or store them in plain text.

What if two users have the same name and password? The more information you have to differentiate the users, the easier it will be to protect the account, and to identify the proper user.

Your responsibility as a developer isn't with ensuring that the user's email is secure. That's the responsibility of the email provider. Just make sure what you are writing and pushing is.

The accepted answer on [this Stackexchnage question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/73024/what-best-practices-should-be-employed-in-a-php-login-script) addresses this rather well. You might have a look.